# How to select a row who has a substring

Tags: sql, select

I have and data like :

```
ID term score
1 enthusiastic 0.986
2 excellence 0.984
3 loves 0.984
4 inspirational 0.984
5 proud 0.68
6 love 0.90
7 so proud 0.71
8 so so proud 0.90
```

I want to get a score whose term includes 'proud'. I searched but can't find anything. As you know `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE term = 'proud'` will return just term who has `'proud'` certainly (will return 5 proud 0.68 only).
I think the problem is so easy but My mind is freeze now.

Thanks for helping

**Expected Output:**

```
5 proud 0.68
7 so proud 0.71
8 so so proud 0.90
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `like` operator instead of `=`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE term like '%proud%'
```

Comment: Really. I used before `like 'proud'` without missing `%`. Thank you.